# Trying to convert TimeSpan to a String using a valueconverter in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use a valueconverter to convert a timespan to a string.

My code thus far is:

```
          entity.Property(e => e.DropOffTime).HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                x => TimeSpan.Parse(x));
```

When I try to run this conversion I get the following error:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.String'.

It seems like this should be straight forward.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong??

PS: I also tried the build in:

```
 var timeStringConverter = new TimeSpanToStringConverter();
 entity.Property(e => e.PickupTime).HasConversion(timeStringConverter);
```

and I got the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the defination for `DropOffTime`?

Comment: DropOffTime is a TimeSpan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [reference documentation for `ValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.valueconversion.valueconverter?view=efcore-2.1)

**ConvertFromProvider**

> Gets the function to convert objects when *reading* data from the store, setup to handle nulls, boxing, and non-exact matches of simple types.

**ConvertToProviderExpression**:

> Gets the function to convert objects when *writing* data to the store, setup to handle nulls, boxing, and non-exact matches of simple types.

So 'from', and 'to' are the point of view of the store, the database.

In the overload...

> ```cs
> .HasConversion(v => v.ToString(), x => TimeSpan.Parse(x))
> ```

...the first expression parameter is named 'convertToProviderExpression', the second one 'convertFromProviderExpression'. That means that the conversion writes a `TimeSpan` as string *to* the database and reads a string *from* the database and converts it into `TimeSpan`. Therefore, the database field must be a string.

The exception you get occurs when the database field is a `time` datatype. The converter expects a string, but receives a `TimeSpan`. The standard error for any .Net method receiving the wrong type is the error you get. In this context that's a somewhat confusing error.

Comment: Thanks!! That was it :-)